# Minipage alternately indenting

Tags: minipage, alignment

Minipage seems to be adding an extra space before "text" on the first and third rows of minipages.  This disrupts the alignment of the fbox.  What is causing this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text 1\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text1a\strut
\end{minipage}
}\\\\
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text2\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text2a\strut
\end{minipage}
}\\\\
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text3\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text3a\strut
\end{minipage}
}\\\\
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text4\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text4a\strut
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are inconsistent sometimes `\fbox{ X }` sometimes `\fbox{X }`

Comment: You can add `%` in the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the spaces yourself.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\fbox
{% <---
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text 1\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}
\fbox
{% <---
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text1a\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}

\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text2\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text2a\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}

\fbox
{% <---
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text3\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}
\fbox
{% <---
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text3a\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}

\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text4\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}
\fbox
{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text4a\strut
\end{minipage}% <---
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better to define your own environment for such jobs.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\newenvironment{fminipage}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}\begin{minipage}}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text 1\strut
\end{fminipage}
\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text1a\strut
\end{fminipage}

\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text2\strut
\end{fminipage}
\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text2a\strut
\end{fminipage}

\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text3\strut
\end{fminipage}
\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text3a\strut
\end{fminipage}

\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text4\strut
\end{fminipage}
\begin{fminipage}[t][3cm][t]{6cm}
text4a\strut
\end{fminipage}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.